# ArcMap 10.6: Is it possible to extract point values from points?

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, merge, extract, values

I've got three point shapes with different fields that I cannot seem to merge as I get ERROR 000229: cannot open 'name of shapefile'. Instead of solving this error, I wanted to try something different: in edit mode, I selected and copied all points into a new shapefile. However, all attributes got lost.

Now I would like to somehow migrate the values from the field 'TOP', which is present in all source shapefiles, to the new shapefile.

I know there is a possibility to extract values from a raster dataset ('Extract Values to Points'). Is it also possible to extract values FROM points, to points in a different shp if they are in the exact same location?

EDIT: In a comment below, I was advised to try Spatial Join which by the look of it would suit my needs perfectly, except that I get the same ERROR 000229. 
I guess I just have to solve my initial problem.

Comment: What you're describing should be fairly simple in ArcMap. Can you elaborate a bit more about the process you've attempted, like what "copied" actually means? Also, have you attempted to use a Spatial Join?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'll edit the question. After reading your comment I've tried spatial join (which looks to be exactly what I need) but it fails, producing the same error message as I got during my attempts to merge: "ERROR 000229: Cannot open shapefile".

Comment: I think I should try and solve the initial error before asking further. Thanks very much for the tip on Spatial Join!

Comment: It's not clear if the error is occurring for all your 3 shapefiles or just one of them? Try starting a blank mxd and load each one into the map, does one fail to load? If all three are failing then it would suggest you have corrupted data. A classic error made by people is not to provide all the files that make up a shapefile. A shapefile is at least 4 files, more depending if other things have been done to it. If you have been just sent the "shp" then you will never be able to use these datasets.

Comment: The error occurred for all three shapefiles. I suspect the shapefiles were still locked because of the earlier edit session (even though I had already stopped it). After rebooting the computer, I was able to merge and use spatial join. Problem solved!

Comment: @JoshC, your comment to use Spatial Join answered my question. Should you want to provide this as an answer rather than a comment, then I'll mark the question as solved. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the points are in the *exact* same position, you can use the **Spatial Join** tool, which is the **Analysis > Overlay** toolbox. This tool merges the geometry, but retains each layer's attributes separately in the output. The merge tool would simply put all your points into a single layer, effectively giving you a single-layer version of the same problem you're trying to solve.

With multiple layers, you'll have to run the tool a couple times, or throw it into a simple model:

[image: two-join model]